# C# Enum ignores names' order

Tags: c#, enums

I have the next object:

```
private enum Operation
{
        Power = 0x5E,             // ^
        Division = 0x2F,          // /
        Multiplication = 0x2A,    // *
        Subtraction = 0x2D,      // -
        Addition = 0x2B           // +
}
```

When I want to convert it into a `char[]` in the next way:

```
private static char[] GetOperators()
{
        List<char> ExistingOperators = new List<char>();

        foreach (Operation enumOperator in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Operation)))
        {
                ExistingOperators.Add((char)enumOperator);
                Console.WriteLine(enumOperator);
        }

        return ExistingOperators.ToArray<char>();
}
```

It writes on the console the values of the enums, but in sorted from small to big.
The above example outputs:

```
Multiplication
Addition
Subtraction
Divison
Power
```

What I want to achieve: (so the array is in the same order as the `enum` declaration)

```
char[] { '^', '/', '*', '*', '-', '*' };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use some sort of sorted list with IComparer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a8xew6.aspx

Comment: The order enum is stored is by its value, what you can have is to sort them by name (just Using .OrderBy(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(Operation), x)). The order of declaration isn't preserved at all. What you can do (if you really need it...) is to apply some custom attribute and to use it for ordering (something like DisplayOrderAttribute).

Comment: A better solution (both for future extensions and for your actual problem) is to **do not use enum** at all. Create a base class Operation with a private constructor and many constants fields (Addition, Multiplication, ...). Declaration order is preserved (**so weak**!!!) and you'll get other benefits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (that is, by their unsigned magnitude).

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the source, clarifies what my mistake was. But still, how can I maintain the same order when I declare the enum?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something along these lines to maintain order and associate a value. Note that the code is freehand (untested).

```
public ValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public char Value { get; set; }
    public ValueAttribute(char value) { Value = value; }
}

private enum Operation
{
    [Value(0x5E)]
    Power = 1,
    [Value(0x2F)]
    Division = 2,
    [Value(0x2A)]
    Multiplication = 3,
    [Value(0x2D)]
    Subtraction = 4,
    [Value(0x2B)]
    Addition = 5,
}

private static char[] GetOperators()
{
    List<char> ExistingOperators = new List<char>();

    foreach (Operation enumOperator in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Operation)))
    {
            ExistingOperators.Add(enumOperator.Value());
            Console.WriteLine(enumOperator);
    }

    return ExistingOperators.ToArray<char>();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static char Value(this Operation op)
    {
        var attr = typeof(Operation)
            .GetField(op.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValueAttribute), false)[0]
            as ValueAttribute;
        return attr.Value;
    }
}
```

Alternate using IndexAttribute:

```
public IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IndexAttribute(int index) { Index = index; }
}

private enum Operation
{
    [Index(1)]
    Power = 0x5E,
    [Index(2)]
    Division = 0x2F,
    [Index(3)]
    Multiplication = 0x2A,
    [Index(4)]
    Subtraction = 0x2D,
    [Index(5)]
    Addition = 0x2B,
}

public struct Datum
{
    int Index { get; set; }
    char Value { get; set; }
    Operation Op { get; set; }
}
private static char[] GetOperators()
{
    IEnumerable<Datum> data = new List<Datum>();

    foreach (Operation enumOperator in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Operation)))
    {
        data.Add(new Datum 
        { 
            Index = enumOperator.Index(), 
            Value = (char)enumOperator,
            Op = enumOperator
        });
    }

    // assuming you can use LINQ
    data = data.OrderBy(d => d.Index);
    data.Foreach(d => Console.WriteLine(d => d.Op));

    return data.Select(d => d.Value).ToArray();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static char Index(this Operation op)
    {
        var attr = typeof(Operation)
            .GetField(op.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false)[0]
            as IndexAttribute;
        return attr.Index;
    }
}
```

Comment: A PositionAttribute may be better, storing ordinal information while keeping the enum values where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @SimonSvensson. Sure. This is just one example. OrdinalAttribute/IndexAttribute/PositionAttribute would achieve the same goal.